# Metal gate slide bolt jammed

Tags: lock, gates

I have a black metal gate at the back of the garden which was installed about 12 months ago. When going to open the gate this morning, the key fits in the lock, but doesn't turn fully to allow the lock to open.

Any ideas how I can get the gate opened without breaking the lock?

Comment: Try spraying some penetrating oil into lock and try lifting/moving gate in case it has sagged and is jamming lock.

Comment: +1 for the gate sagging or warping putting pressure on the lock internals - apply some up/down/push/pull combinations of forces to the gate to see if it achieves release (of the lock, but maybe also of the pent up anger towards it :D )

Comment: I use powdered graphite in locks as suggested by a locksmith. The locksmith said liquid lubricants are not as good for locks as powdered graphite.

Comment: @EdBeal powdered graphite is good for maintenance, worked in by turning the key,  but doesn't penetrate when things are already stuck.  With partial movement it may be enough

Comment: @chris H the lock will turn but not completely this is exactly the case that powdered graphite works well to lubricate and not gum up the lock over time.

Comment: @EdBeal I wouldn't use the sort of oil that goes gummy, but I've had jams in parts too far from any access for graphite to get in (e.g. the mechanism above the cylinder that works a multi-point locking system)

Comment: @chris h any place that a spray will go graphite will go. All oils attract dust I use a silicone spray on my table saw it helps wood slide over the surface but it collects dust and I don’t want the black of graphite on my wood. the powdered graphite or a moly MoS2 won’t be affected by cold as sprays are.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the lock is malfunctioning, use a silicone lubricant to see if that helps it turn all the way. It would be a great lube for your outdoor application as well. Silicone spray is water resistant, it also protects items from moisture.

Don't use WD-40 on your locks. It may help to "unstick it" (if the mechanism is the issue). It won't lubricate it, and in time, will likely become difficult to operate again

If it's from the weight of the gate/door causing it to sag and preventing the lock from functioning properly, either adjust the strike plate to allow for some sagging. Or possibly tighten your hinges.

Hope it helps!
*(by the way, Maybe post some pics for reference?)

Comment: I do agree with the sag, and not using WD40 but not any part of a liquid spray as they collect dust and get stiff when cold. I am not a locksmith but that advice has served me well on rental units. It was advice from a locksmith.

Comment: WD40 will help unstick locks, especially exteriors, and shouldn't be explicitly verboten in all cases. It is not ideal to use for regular maintenance for a few reasons, but as a metal cleaner it can work wonders on a jammed/stuck/filthy lock cylinder.